# Use case for using array as ruby hash key

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Ruby allows using an array as a hash key as shown below:

```
hash1 = {1 => "one", [2] => 'two', [3,4] => ['three', 'four']}
```

I am not clear on what common use case for this would be. If people can share some real-world scenarios where this is useful, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Terminology check: `1`, `[2]`, `[3,4]` are not hash indexes, they are hash keys.

Answer (score 2):

A great example why you'd want to store arrays as hash keys is for memoizing.

This is an example of how an array as a hash key is useful:

```
def initialize(*args)
  @memoizer ||= {}
  return @memoizer[args] if @memoizer[args]
  # do what you will with the args in this initializer, 
  # then create a new instance for the future.
  @memoizer[args] = some_calculation(args)
end
```

Comment: @sawa: Not a class, just a general optimization/caching technique. A technique that is harder in, say, Perl where all hash keys are strings.

Comment: In Perl we'd convert the array to a string using something like `"@ary"`, which, in Ruby would be akin to `ary.join(',')` as a key, with the same failing that arrays with their elements in different order would generate different keys, allowing duplicate entries in the hash.

Comment: Or worse (in the Perl case), you'd have to assume that all the arguments could be meaningfully stringified and that's rarely the case with your custom objects.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating things here. It isn't that Arrays are allowed as keys, it is that *almost any* object can be a key. From the [fine manual](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html):

> A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays, but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to use any object type.
>   [...]
>   A user-defined class may be used as a hash key if the `hash` and `eql?` methods are overridden to provide meaningful behavior.

Note that both [`hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) and [`eql?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) are in Object so almost everything you'll come across will have them and so can be a key in a Hash. The default implementations may not be terribly meaningful for some arbitrary object but they'll still be there.

Sometimes generality is easier than artificially limiting your options to only those that the language designer can see a use for. Not even [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is that strict.

I guess what I'm trying to say is that I think you're asking the wrong question. The question you should be asking is:

> Why should you be forbidden from using an Array as a Hash key?

This is Ruby where (almost) everything is allowed by default so the answer to that question is that we don't want to artificially limit your options, here's a big pile of possibilities, go do something wonderful and unexpected with it.

Answer (score 0):

If the key has some structure, you may want to directly use that:

```
{
  %w[John Travolta] => :foo,
  %w[Olivia Newton John] => :bar,
}
```

Initial state of Othello/Reversi board

```
Hash.new(:green).merge{
  [4, :d] => :white,
  [4, :e] => :black,
  [5, :d] => :black,
  [5, :e] => :white,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From your example it seems like it could be used to more efficiently store large and/or sparse matrices. As you can see, if 3 and 4 both share the same values, they can be "compacted" into a single reference. There may be more formal data structures that would use this, but it's been a while since I used "formal" data structures, so I can't think of any off hand.